# React Router Dom (v 6.4.3) page becomes unresponsive after navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

My page is becoming unresponsive when I try to navigate using useNavigate or a Link in my component. After clicking a button or link, the url will change, and the javascript inside the target component will execute, but the page does not re-render. useNavigate works with other components in my app, so I'm not quite sure what the issue is. Any input would be appreciated!

Dashboard.js:

```
import { useNavigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Dashboard = () => {
  console.log("hello from dashboard");
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div>
      <Link className="pl-20" to="/test">
        test
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Test.js:

```
import React from "react";

const Test = () => {
  console.log("hello from test page");
  return <div>this is the test page</div>;
};

export default Test;
```

App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import Test from "./pages/Test";


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/test" element={<Test />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

[gif showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJojQ.gif)

Comment: Is it specifically the `"/create-profile"` route and `CreateProfile` component with the issue, or is it any route and component? Can you [edit] the post to include the relevant routed component you suspect has the performance issue? Where is the router rendered? See [mcve]. It sounds like you've a component render looping. I don't think it is a router/routing/navigation issue considering you navigated to `"/dashboard"` and rendered the `Dashboard` component.

Comment: Have you checked the new way to configure react router dom v6.4+ using `createBrowserRouter` and `RouterProvider` may be it works for you

Comment: Did you wrap all the routes inside <BrowserRouter /> ??

Comment: Thank you for your answers! @DrewReese I thought it may be from a component render looping as well, but this is occurring with a small test component I created. I also added a gif showing the issue.

Comment: I don't see any issue with this specific code. Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Answer (score 1):

you gave pl-20 class on Dashboard. but not on Test component.
Please check.